# Divide-and-conquer approach for simple array algorithm

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a divide-and-conquer approach that points out the first number in a list that does not follow a n+1 sequence. And if all of them do follow the sequence, return `-1`.

So for example, if I have an array of numbers of size 8:

```
int size = 9;
int listofNumbers[9] = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 6, 7 };
```

I would need a function that scans the array and returns `3`, since it's the first one that fails to meet the n+1 sequence.

I made an approach using iteration, and it works:

```
int findFirst_iterative(int list[], int listSize)
{
    if (listSize < 1)
    {
        return -1; // empty list.
    }

    int nextNumber = list[0]; // we start with the first number in the list.

    for (int i = 1; i < listSize; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] != (nextNumber + 1))
        {
            return list[i];
        }

        nextNumber = list[i];
    }

    return -1;
}
```

I am now trying to do the same but using a divide-and-conquer approach.

```
int findFirst_divideandconquer(int list[], int listSize)
{
    if (listSize < 1)
    {
        return -1; // the list is empty.
    }
    else if (listSize == 2)
    {
        if (list[1] != list[0] + 1)
        {
            return list[1];
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    int mid = listSize / 2;
    int listhalfA[mid];
    int listhalfB[mid];

    int overallindex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++)
    {
        listhalfA[i] = list[overallindex];
        overallindex = overallindex + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++)
    {
        listhalfB[i] = list[overallindex];
        overallindex = overallindex + 1;
    }

    int resultA = findFirst_divideandconquer(listhalfA, mid);
    if (resultA == -1)
    {
        int resultB = findFirst_divideandconquer(listhalfB, mid);
        if (resultB == -1)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return resultB;
    }
    return resultA;
}
```

I've hit a roadblock, while I succeeded in dividing the list in halves, it will return the second number that fails to meet the sequence, instead of the first one. So the code above returns `6` instead of `3`, which is what I need.
How could I fix this?

Comment: If you want to do this for learning then do your thing. Otherwise, stick to the iteration solution as it already is the most efficient solution for this task.

Comment: Before being able to fix the issue you need to find the root cause. What debugging did you do? Did you run your code in a debugger and step thru it  (or even just added more debug prints) to find where it first starts to fail? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `int mid = listSize / 2; int listhalfA[mid]; int listhalfB[mid];` This won't work for odd sized arrays as it will miss one element - which is the case in the code shown. For odd sized arrays one half will have one more element than the other half.

Comment: Instead of `int listhalfB[mid];`, use `int listhalfB[listSize - mid];`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for this task there is no point in using divide and conquer other than learning. Your iterative solution is the fastest approach. Only if you wanted *any* non-consecutive number instead of the *first* one, divide and conquer could be faster.

Your divide and conquer approach has three problems. Two small bugs and a theoretical flaw:

1. As [kaylum pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68855600/divide-and-conquer-approach-for-simple-array-algorithm#comment121688786_68855600), `int mid = listSize / 2; int listhalfA[mid]; int listhalfB[mid];` might skip an element. If `listSize` is odd then `mid+mid < listSize` because of integer division. To fix this, use `int listhalfB[mid]; int listhalfB[listSize-mid];`.
2. Your trivial case `listSize < 1` should be `listSize < 2`. Because of the bug above this wasn't a problem so far.
3. Divide and conquer requires to combine the solutions of the partial problems. In your combination step, you just picked the first solution that isn't `-1`. But this is not sufficient. If you split the array `1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13` into `1, 2, 3` and `11, 12, 13` you'd get the solutions `-1` and `-1` and therefore would return `-1` even though the correct solution would be `11`. The combination step needs to consider the numbers at the boundary too. An elegant way to do this is by breaking the array into two overlapping pieces `0 <= A <= mid` and `mid <= B <= listSize-1`.

By the way: You waste a lot of code lines and execution time for copying the array. It would be easier and faster to specify start and end indices of the existing array instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int findFirstIntern(int list[], int start, int endExclusive) {
    int listSize = endExclusive - start;
    if (listSize < 2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (listSize == 2) {
        if (list[start+1] != list[start]+1) {
            return list[start+1];
        }
        return -1;
    }
    int mid = start + listSize/2;
    int result = findFirstIntern(list, start, mid+1);
    if (result != -1) {
        return result;
    }
    return findFirstIntern(list, mid, endExclusive);
}

int findFirst(int list[], int listSize) {
    return findFirstIntern(list, 0, listSize);
}

int main() {
    int list[] = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 6, 7};
    int first = findFirst(list, sizeof(list)/sizeof(int));
    printf("First non-consecutive number is %d\n", first);
    return 0;
}
```

If you return the *index* of the non-consecutive number instead of the number itself, this solution would also work with negative numbers.